# Why Shivalinga sthapana in temple is unique in Hinduism?

Tags: shiva, temple, shiva-lingam

I have seen that in many hindu temples, all other deity's statues are brought from the entrance of the temple and some *"Pran Pratistha"* ritual *Vidhi*(method) is performed.

> But when the *shiva Linga* is established, the roof is cut and `Shiva Linga_ is established from sky only!!

In gujarat,India in one temple, I have seen such establishment of Shiva Linga. So because of my curious nature, I asked people why such a unique way of Shiva Linga only? Other statues were taken from entrance only..

They said, Shiva is unborn, so his incarnation is not possible from any mother's womb. So in hinduism Shiva linga is established from sky, means the Shiva directly comes from sky(Paramdham or Kailash) only.

Does anybody know about this? Is there any explanation in some hindu scripture?

But I heard this again from *Pujari* also. I asked some Brahmakumari sisters also to verify, they also told me the same thing. So I trusted what everybody told me. But now this made me more curious about this. Can anybody please cite some sources?

Comment: Lord Shiva is source of Eternal knowlenge.and knowledge doesnt come from eyes,ears,mouth...etc or any direction. Knowledge emerge in mind when sadhak in "samadhi".(samadhi is a position where sadhak has no matter of existence of his material body) Thats why SHIVA LINGAM is established from Sky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is truth value in what they said. The *linga* from of Shiva denotes the unborn supreme Brahman. The origin of *linga* has been described in Shiva Purana, Linga Purana, etc. The *linga* denotes a column of fire that extends infinitely from top to bottom without a middle:

> *etasminnantare liṃgamabhavaccāvayoḥ puraḥ
>
> vivādaśamanārthaṃ hi prabodhārthaṃ ca bhāsvaram
>
> jvālāmālāsahasrāḍhyaṃ kālānalaśatopamam
>
> kṣayavṛddhivinirmuktamādimadhyāṃtavarjitam*  [LP - 17.33,34]
>
> **Meaning**
> Then after that a bright *linga* appeared between both of us to counsel our arguments. That linga was surrounded by thousands of flames and hot like fire of death. Without any beginning and end, that was free from decay and growth.

As per the *Shaiva Puranas* the linga form appeared before Brahma and Vishnu to solve their dispute regarding who is supreme between them.

## Installation

Regarding it's installation, it is not compulsory to install the *linga* from the sky alone. The *linga* can be taken into the temple through the open doors or through predetermined place for doors present in the particular direction. But in the absence of such appropriate doors, the rule is to install the *linga* from sky  without touching the door or by taking it over the stone that will be used to close the doors (*dwara bandha*):

> *lingaṃ samsthāpya datvārghya prāsādaṃ sanniveśayet
>
> dvāreṇa dvārabandhena dvaradeśena tacchilā
>
> dvārabandhe śikhaśunye tadardhenātha tadrute
>
> varjayan dvārasamsparśaṃ dvāreṇaiva mahesvaram* [Agni. Pu. - 97.21,22]
>
> **Meaning**
> After offering *arghya* to the *linga* install it in the temple by taking it through the open door or through the doorstep (*dwara bandaha*) without touching the door. Otherwise, install the God from the sky taking it over the doorstep.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

**Telling from vedas** is all more different from what you see in real world.Vedas tells about how to make a man reach highest position ie Samadarshi or universal brotherhood.Temples are representations of the principle for attaining same.

**TEMPLE**: Normally  learned as place for workship. But in olden days Guru and students aka Shishyas stay at Mahashala(now called as temples). Guru teaches student his lessons to attain Honorable position of Samadarshi. after teaching he is shifted to other place for practicing what he had learned, that place is parikshith.So as centuries moved on these 2 structures remained , the mahashala became normal temple and other became SHiva temple.

**Shivalinga :**
According to Vedas Shivalinga Represents the shape of the Paramanu aka GOD particle (most minute particle by which the universe was created by god) when it enters divinity.
Its not to be compared with shape of any human organs.

**Unique to Hinduism:**
Since Hinduism is the only Science which tells about paramanu, its unique to hinduism. Its written in Vedas how the universe has came into existence. Its has been given very very descriptively. But problem with Vedas is that it is written in vyanjaka language. This language takes a style which leads a person to think the different from what is written and its true meaning can only be gained by the person who is equivalent in greatness to the one who have written it or say who have found the truth within.

So a Person equivalent to MahaRishis who have written the Vedas can only decipher it.

Comment: Welcome to HSE. We except some citations to support the answers.  The sources need not necessarily be the scriptures but it should be a respected source. the answer is well written, but please try to add some sources for the claims. Further, just for information, the sciences of Ancient Egyptians and Dogons of Central Africa too have spoken about 'paramanu' - i the Dogon mythology it is referred to as 'Po'. But yes the scientific knowledge in Indian scriptures is truly astounding.