# What is the ritual procedure for linga sthapana in a temple?

Tags: shiva, rituals, temple, shiva-lingam, pranapratishtha

In our native place we bhakthakodees are planning to place a shiv Ling in the existing temple. Can someone throw some light on the procedure of installing shiv ling in temple and also if there are any prescribed dimensions (height, width of the three parts) of the lingam?

Primarily I am asking the about the rituals before the installation like:

1. What homam has to be done?
2. Are Astabandham rituals to be done for the first installation?
3. Does the shivling have to undergo 18 days or 41 days rituals (not sure about the procedure).
4. What should be the dimension of the shivling sculptured?

Comment: The procedure to install any idol in temple or any common place is known as Prana prathishta of that Idol, so this question may related to this one http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/how-to-do-prana-pratishtha-of-idols

Comment: the link you have shared has nothing related to the Linga sthapana..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Shivalinga sthapana in temple is unique in Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/why-shivalinga-sthapana-in-temple-is-unique-in-hinduism)

Comment: @The Destroyer please read my question completely and then kindly suggest.this question is not a duplication

Comment: What temple it is? You need to consult an expert in this. Anyways, i can provide the answer as per Puranas but i suggest you to consult an expert in this as temple was already built.

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks :)..your answers are most welcome

Comment: @sritharan You didn't get me. You can't simply install Shiva Lingam by my answer which is described in Agni purana and Matysa Purana. Also, You must consult an expert.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ok i will consult with an expert on this.